# jQuery on button click find tag of <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've the following code:

```
<ul data-role='listview' id='the-listview' data-inset='true' data-corners='false'>
    <li data-tag="<?php echo $id . "|" . "age"; ?>">
        <img src='images/photo.png' class='main-photo'/>
        <label class='name'><?php echo $name; ?></label>
        <p class='country'><?php echo $country; ?></p>
        <img src='images/edit.png' id='edit-info' style='cursor: pointer'/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to when click the image "edit-info", retrieve the `<li data-tag>` values. Unsuccessfully tried:

```
$("#edit-info").on("click", function(){
    alert($(this).find('li').attr('data-tag'));
});
```

It retrieves 'undefined'.

Comment: Have you looked in the DOM, does the `li` item actually have a value on the data-tag attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find()` is designed to find child elements. In this case, the `li` is the parent element, so use `closest()` instead:

```
alert($(this).closest('li').attr('data-tag'));
```

Comment: one more thing, I've tried ot get the value of the class 'country', without success. `$(this).closest('.country').val();`, I do receive 'undefined'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `.find()` in this context. It will look for the `descendants`. `.Closest()` will be the correct choice at this moment, because it will travel up the DOM tree and select the elements according to the `selector`.

Try,

```
$("#edit-info").on("click", function(){
    alert($(this).closest('li').data('tag'));
});
```

Comment: Your solution is correct, but one more thing, I've tried to get the value of the class 'country', without success. `$(this).closest('.country').val();` I do receive 'undefined'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user3065191 You can use either like `$(this).prev('.country').text()` or `$(this).closest('li').find('.country').text()`

Answer (score 0):

that is because you are not using the correct attribute.

If you want to use `find()` then please first

1. go to the parent element
2. then find the child!

Like this:

```
$(this).parent().attr('data-tag')
```

This will work!

This code will go to the parent element; since  the image is in the element the `li` is in. So, find would find the child elements only. So, go to the parent element using `.parent()` and then come back to its child using `find()`.